# Changes form a master slide are not applied for web Powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins, powerpoint-web-addins

I try to change a text in a shape on a master slide with code:

```
PowerPoint.run(function(context) {
var masterSlideShape = context.presentation.slideMasters.getItemAt(0).shapes.getItemAt(5);
masterSlideShape .textFrame.textRange.text = 'Some text';
return context.sync();
});
```

This works fine with desktop PowerPoint. But when it comes to web version, changes are not applied immediately. They are applied only after I refresh a page.

When I work with slides which are not master, everything is updated online.

No console errors

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `await` keyword for `async` operations:

```
// This sample creates a rectangle positioned 100 points from the top and left sides
// of the slide and is 150x150 points. The shape is put on the first slide.
await PowerPoint.run(async (context) => {
    const shapes = context.presentation.slides.getItemAt(0).shapes;
    const rectangle = shapes.addGeometricShape(PowerPoint.GeometricShapeType.rectangle);
    rectangle.left = 100;
    rectangle.top = 100;
    rectangle.height = 150;
    rectangle.width = 150;
    rectangle.name = "Square";
    await context.sync();
});
```

Comment: The same result

Comment: I'd suggest posting this as a bug to the Office JS repo at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues .